# A folder lock/encryption program that can do this?

Tags: encryption

I am looking for a program that can lock or encrypt folder, but in case if my laptop is stolen and C drive is reformatted and reinstalled, and i have locked folders on D drive, these folders to remain unaccessible. Also, these folders to remain unaccessible if someone try to use live linux distros from USB drive.

Is there such a program?

Comment: Any software that's doing encryption properly will prevent access to the protected data regardless of what happens to the Operating System - so long as the data is not currently unlocked by an authorized user.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Windows offers this natively. It's called [Encrypting File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) and here is a [quick tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7).

There are also other alternatives. For a long time, truecrypt was the goto software in cases like these, but it got [discontinued (under somewhat dubious circumstances)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt#End_of_life_announcement). There are a lot of [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt#Alternatives) [alternatives](http://lifehacker.com/5677725/five-best-file-encryption-tools) [as](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2304851/so-long-truecrypt-5-encryption-alternatives-that-can-lock-down-your-data.html) [well](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=windows%20encryption%20software). You have to try around and see which one you like best (also google the software you choose, and see if people have any (security) concerns).

Actually discussing the different programs is a little [out of scope on this site](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). See also this question on [alternatives to truecrypt](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt) on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.